# share image from Viewpager using intents works in 4.2.2 but does not work in 2.3, what to do?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-viewpager, share

I'm facing a trouble with sharing images in (android 2.3), I tried sharing in Jelly Bean and it works.
I have tested my application in over 30 devices that run Android 2.3 and all does have the share option not work.
When I click on share button it gives a message that says:
"unable to load the resource".. :/

Here is my code:

```
public class ImagePager extends BaseActivity implements OnClickListener {

    Button share, back;
    private static final String STATE_POSITION = "STATE_POSITION";
    public String image;
    ViewPager pager;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ac_image_pager);

        share = (Button)findViewById(R.id.share);
        back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back);

        share.setOnClickListener(this);
        back.setOnClickListener(this);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String[] imageUrls = bundle.getStringArray(Extra.IMAGES);
        int pagerPosition = bundle.getInt(Extra.IMAGE_POSITION, 0);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            pagerPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_POSITION);
        }

        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(new ImagePagerAdapter(imageUrls));
        pager.setCurrentItem(pagerPosition);    
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt(STATE_POSITION, pager.getCurrentItem());
    }

    private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private String[] images;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        ImagePagerAdapter(String[] images) {
            this.images = images;
            inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
        }

        @Override
        public void finishUpdate(View container) {
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return images.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {


            View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_pager_image, view, false);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
            final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.loading);

            imageLoader.displayImage(images[position], imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                    String message = null;
                    switch (failReason.getType()) {
                        case IO_ERROR:
                            message = "Input/Output error";
                            break;
                        case DECODING_ERROR:
                            message = "Image can't be decoded";
                            break;
                        case NETWORK_DENIED:
                            message = "Downloads are denied";
                            break;
                        case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                            message = "Out Of Memory error";
                            break;
                        case UNKNOWN:
                            message = "Unknown error";
                            break;
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(ImagePager.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

            ((ViewPager) view).addView(imageLayout, 0);
            return imageLayout;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view.equals(object);
        }

        @Override
        public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
        }

        @Override
        public Parcelable saveState() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void startUpdate(View container) {
        }
    }

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.share:
            int position = pager.getCurrentItem();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                image="c1";
                break;
            case 1:
                image="c2";
                break;
            case 2:
                image="c3";
                break;
            case 3:
                image="c4";
                break;
            case 4:
                image="c5";
                       }
        //Here is my share code.... I don't know really what the problem is.
            //And why this not works in Android 2.3


        Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://mypackagename/drawable/"+image);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/jpg");

        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent , "Share"));

            break;

        case R.id.back:
            this.finish();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I have another class for setting images resources, here is the code:

```
public final class Constants {

    public static final String[] IMAGES = new String[] {
        "drawable://" + R.drawable.c1,
        "drawable://" + R.drawable.c2,
        "drawable://" + R.drawable.c3,
        "drawable://" + R.drawable.c4,
        "drawable://" + R.drawable.c5
};

    private Constants() {
    }

    public static class Config {
        public static final boolean DEVELOPER_MODE = false;
    }

    public static class Extra {
        public static final String IMAGES = "mypackagename.IMAGES";
        public static final String IMAGE_POSITION = "mypackagename.IMAGE_POSITION";
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the message "unable to load the resource" show up? Logcat? Toast? Also, take a look at logcat. I'm sure it'll help you figure out what's wrong.

Comment: It showed up like a Toast message, and I don't have like this Toast in my code.. :/

Comment: There is nothing showed in the logcat, I have noticed that some applications like Skype and WeChat are encounter the problem, but What's App, Gmail, Viber do not show this Toast, think the problem is with the shared Uri, any help guys ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem when trying to share bitmap using Images.Media.insertImage(..).
The solution is to add permission: "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" in to your manifest.
It was found that on some devices it works without this permission but sometimes dont, it depends on vendor.

Should help. Good luck.

Comment: I already added this permission to the manifest, it changed nothing.
BTW, thanks for your answer